# ASP.NET MVC: Custom Validation by DataAnnotation depending on configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, viewmodel

I'm using DataAnnotation for client and server validation of my view model. I would like to ask you about the best practices of using custom validation.

I have two forms, which use the same view model:

```
public class RecipientViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }

    public string Address2 { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to achieve, it is that the first form should validate the `Address2` field, but the second form did not. Of course my view model is much bigger and I want to do it generic as much as possible.

Is there any possibility to pass a list of fields to be validated and how? For example view could pass it to view model somehow?

Comment: Short answer is NO. Create separate view models.

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify your question or show more code.
In general the Annotations are very good to check expected structures or a certain kind of expected data. Like length, presence, type.
For other more complicated, complex business cases. Good implementation will have a business layer or a domain design which handles these use cases.
So define your use cases and think about an layer between controller and data model. Maybe something like a validation Services which gets injected into the viewmodel.

HTH

EDIT: You probably want to take a look at - Validating with a Service Layer from the ASP.NET site - http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/models-(data)/validating-with-a-service-layer-cs] which shows some of the conepts - the technology might have changed slightly since the article is from 2009 but you got the idea.

Comment: Do you have any example of validation service injection to viewmodels?